# Docker BaseX DBA

Tags: docker, basex

I use the following docker compose file to start the basexhttp server and the dba:

```
version: '3'

services:
 basexhttp:
  image: basex/basexhttp
  ports:
  - "1984:1984"
  - "8984:8984"

   dba:
  image: basex/dba:8.5.4
  ports:
  - "11984:1984"
  - "18984:8984"
  - "18985:8985"
```

According to the documentation I should get the dba page with:
`http://<host>:18984/dba`.

Returns `No function found that matches the request.`

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Hi bergtwvd — I am sorry but your example is slightly outdated, we no longer maintain a separate basex/dba image — mostly due to our DBA no longer supporting connecting to remote basex instances..

I think the best approach is building your own image based on our "official" basexhttp image, that contains the DBA code:

1. Download BaseX.zip from http://files.basex.org/releases/
2. Create an empty folder for building your docker image.
3. Create a Dockerfile inside that folder with the following contents:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM basex/basexhttp:9.1
MAINTAINER BaseX Team 
ADD ./webapp /srv/basex/webapp
```

4. Copy the webpapp folder contained in `basex.zip` into the same folder your Dockerfile is in
5. Run docker build:

```
# docker build
docker build -t mydba .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  685.6kB
Step 1/3 : FROM basex/basexhttp:latest
  ---> c9efb2903a40
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER BaseX Team 
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 11228f6d7b17
Step 3/3 : COPY webapp /srv/basex/
  ---> Using cache
  ---> d209f033d6d9
Successfully built d209f033d6d9
Successfully tagged mydba:latest
```

You may as well use this technique with docker-compose:
`#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  dba:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8984:8984"`

You should now be able to open http://localhost:8984 and access the DBA.

Hope this helps.

Comment: running this docker container of basex requires a web app?